# How to use List.fold_left to populate keys of empty string map in ocaml?

Tags: ocaml

I have an existing list, which I would like to move into a empty StringMap. I just want the items in this list to become the keys of said StringMap.

This is what I'm trying to do right now:

```
utop # List.fold_left StringMap.empty [1,2,3];;
Error: This expression has type 'a StringMap.t
       but an expression was expected of type 'b -> 'c -> 'b
```

But clearly it's wrong as I'm getting the above error message

How should I go about this? Thanks in advance

Comment: What is a StringMap? Is it Map.Make(String)?

Comment: You should really learn to read [documentation](https://ocaml.org/api/List.html#VALfold_left). It will save you from asking most of these extremely basic questions.

Comment: Also, the separator inside the List is `;` and not `,` in OCaml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List.fold_left` takes three parameters: a function to be "folded", an initial value, and the list to be processed. You're only supplying two parameters. You need to supply a function that processes each element of the list and produces an intermediate result.

Here is an example that adds up all the elements of a list:

```
# List.fold_left (fun a b -> a + b) 0 [1;3;5;7];;
- : int = 16
```

You need a function like the one above except that it should add an element to the map.